# How to print a list using class methods

Tags: python

I have the following class which is designed to print a list where the length of the list varies with the number of arguments entered by the user. It is as follows:

```
class ListCreator:
    def __init__(self, *i):
        self.list = [i]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list)
```

When I try to run the following code:

```
print(ListCreator(4,'Hi',5,6))
```

The result is this:

```
[(4, 'Hi', 5, 6)]
```

How can I change this so the end result is not a tuple consisting of the elements, so it is rather like this:

```
[4,'Hi',5,6]
```

I have tried running an if statement to test whether the element is a tuple and then if so, append each element of the tuple into a new list and set self.list to the new list, however I was wondering if there is a nicer way of doing so, especially for the case in which:

```
print(Circularlist())
```

should output:

```
[]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `self.list = list(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `[i]`, you make a list and put `i` in the first index. `i` is a tuple. You can convert the tuple directly to a list like this:

```
self.list = list(i)
```